# Is it recommended to use characters like this one " / " for SKU's in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, character, space, sku

Is it recommended to use characters like this one " / " and spaces for SKU's in Woocommerce? 
I wonder if it will have or create an impact on speed or can bring other issues? 
Can anyone please let me know it if that is OK?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As someone who manages a WooCommerce store with 3,000+ products, I would say that using "/" (slashes), spaces or any characters in sku numbers **will not negatively affect** the performance of your store since sku numbers and other text account for such a small piece of data when a product page or any product data is rendered. However, I will say that with my experience managing so many products, it is best to leave spaces out of sku numbers, but slashes are fine for the sake of readability for both you and your customers.

Hope that helps. Good luck!